# Ethereum 2nd Layer Solutions, Side-Chains, Child-Chains, Root-Chains:

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, remix, dapp-development, sidechain

There are many projects implementing a so-called side-chain or a new chain which works as 2nd layer solution. What does this mean technically? How can one connect a 2nd layer chain with a root-chain e.g. Ethereum?

If anyone can cut this out in simple terms, or provide useful ressources, it would be very appreciated.